# Configure output channel for service activator via .handle()

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

**Edited**
I am new to Spring integration, and I am trying to pass data from a service activator(via handle method) to a channel.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow processFileFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from("fileInputChannel")
            .transform(fileToStringTransformer())
            .handle("fileProcessor", "process")
            .channel("xmlChannel")
            .get();
}

@Bean
public DirectChannel fileInputChannel(){
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
public DirectChannel xmlChannel(){
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
public FileProcessor fileProcessor() {
    return new FileProcessor();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow enrichDataFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from("xmlChannel")
            .handle("enricher", "enrichProduct")
            .channel("bvChannel")
            .get();
}

@Bean
public Enricher enricher() {
    return new Enricher();
}
```

This is the FileProcessor class

```
public class FileProcessor {

    @ServiceActivator(outputChannel = "xmlChannel")
    public String process(Message<String> msg) {
        String content = msg.getPayload();
        return content;
    }
}
```

This is the Enricher class:
    public class Enricher {

```
    public void enrichProduct(Message<String> msg) {
        System.out.println("Enriching product " + msg);
    }
}
```

The message "Enriching product .." isn't getting printed, and I'm not really sure of what has gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't that `.channel("xmlChannel")` work for you?

That's definitely the proper way to compose `IntegrationFlow` - from one endpoint over a message channel to another endpoint.

And I would say that `outputChannel = "xmlChannel"` in the `@ServiceActivator` isn't going to work just  because there is no `inputChannel`. More over the `.handle()` will just ignore all those attributes and just will deal with the `fileProcessor.process()` method directly.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'm deducing that .channel("xmlChannel") isn't working because there's another Integration Flow defined in the same file. I'll edit the details in the question accordingly.

Comment: Is `fileOrocessor` invoked anyway? You can turn on debug logging for `org.springframework.integration` category to see how your messages travel through the flow